Extract features using deep learning
If I want to extract images' features using a deep learning algorithm without classification, how can I do it, and how can I pass the generated output into another model?

# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['image'].tolist(), df['dx'].tolist(), test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Load the pre-trained ResNet-50 model
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
# Extract features using ResNet-50
def extract_features(images):
    X = np.array([preprocess_input(img) for img in images])
    features = model.predict(X)
    return features.reshape(len(X), -1)

# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['image'].tolist(), df['dx'].tolist(), test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Filter out the None values
X_train = [x for x in X_train if x is not None]
X_test = [x for x in X_test if x is not None]

# Extract features for training and testing sets - this is not working
X_train_features = extract_features(X_train)
X_test_features = extract_features(X_test)

